# How to use bindToController, controller, controllerAs and require options instead of simply the link function with isolated scope in this directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**The scenario:**

Say I want to create a drop in component which is basically a form that needs to take some input from the user, validate it and save it on the server. And I need to expose some callbacks so that the user of the directive can do what he needs based on the server response or user clicking the cancel button. I want this to be an element directive `<new-product-widget></new-product-widget>`. Now how do I go about doing this? From my point of view I can simply isolate the scope of the directive and accept functions from the enclosing controller as attributes; Ex:

```
<new-product-widget on-success="ctrl.onAddSuccess" on-error="ctrl.onAddError" on-cancel="ctrl.onAddCancel" on-invalid="ctrl.onAddInvalid"></new-product-widget>
```

and then use them inside my link function. However after going through the directive docs I think there is a better way to do this using the  `bindToController`, `controller`, `controllerAs` and `require` options. However I am confused as to how I can rewrite this using these features and the precise benefits it will provide. Any links to blogs/videos explaining these by example would be a great help.

*Please read the original description it might help you in understanding my confusion.*

Original description.

> I want to get into writing isolated shareable directives (components).
>   The angular documentation suggests that these options are related.
>
> My understanding:
>
> - `Controller` allows me to define a controller constructor. (What special powers does this give me. What should I be doing/not doing in
>     here)
> - `ControllerAs` allows an alias for the controller inside directive    scope. (Why would I need access to the constructor? Am I supposed to
>     instantiate it manually)
> - `Require` angular doc says - *Require another directive and inject its controller as the fourth argument to the linking function.* 
>     (eh..? Why? How?)
> - `bindToController` angular doc says - *When an isolate scope is used for a component (see above), and controllerAs is used,
>     `bindToController: true` will allow a component to have its properties
>     bound to the controller, rather than to scope. When the controller is
>     instantiated, the initial values of the isolate scope bindings are
>     already available.* (I don't understand this option at all.)
>
> Can you explain with an example how to use these options together and
>   what they allow me to achieve which I can't with the link function? I
>   am very confused.
>
> *I am using angular version 1.4.x*
>
> [Angular Doc I read.][1]
>
> [1]: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: so, you want sample for all four property, or just some of them?

Comment: you have multiple interconnected questions here, all of which have been answered on this site in some form on this site already.

Comment: I would probably start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641478/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445928/why-isnt-my-directives-selection-being-bound-to-the-controller/33446448#33446448

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903887/bindtocontroller-with-require-in-angular-directive

Comment: @Grundy an example using all of em would be the best. But an example with some of them and an explanation of when and how to use the rest in relation would be great as well.

Comment: @Kasahs, from doc: _controller: This allows the directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's behavior._, also see link provides Claies, it a bit explain how it use

Comment: @Kasahs, in nutshell: in `controller`: you can create api that can be use another directives where in `require` set your directive. `controllerAs` - avail use in directive template referens to your controller, and `bindToController` map property from `scope` object in your directive to your controller, so if you define: `scope: { myAttr: '=' }` you can use it in template controller as `ctrl.myAttr`